# How to action a rest request after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, rest

Trying to do the following, created this simple form for for a test:

```
<form name="input" action"submit.jsp" method="get">
Change background-color:&nbsp;#<input type="text">&nbsp;<input type="submit"value="submit">

</form>
```

I am trying to, on clicking the button to take the value from the text box and insert that into a link (which is going to be a rest request) and action it.

I of course need to make sure no one can see the user and password I will pass along the request as well, can someone point me in the right direction of where to start?

I was thinking maybe to use

```
document.getElementById("id")
```

And have the input as:

```
<input name="bgcolor" id="bgcolor">
```

I'm just not sure how to execute and hide a rest request with a password inside.

To get

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate?

Comment: Yep :) I do have SSL for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be completed using the following:

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-getelementbyid.php